# Match very specific open and close brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to modify some LaTeX Beamer code, and want to do a quick regex find a certain pattern that defines a block of code. For example, in

```
\only{
      \begin{equation*}
            \psi_{w}(B)(1-B)^{d}y_{t,w} = x^{T}_{t,w}\gamma_{w} + \eta_{w}(B)z_{t,w},
            \label{eq:gen_arima}
        \end{equation*}
    }
```

I want to match just the `\only{` and the final `}`, and nothing else, to remove them. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want to remove \only{ and }, and keep everything within it`

---

On a PCRE (php), Perl, Notepad++ it's done like this:

For something as simple as this, all you need is
Find `\\only\s*({((?:[^{}]++|(?1))*)})`
Replace `$2`

https://regex101.com/r/U3QxGa/1

Explained

```
 \\ only \s*  
 (                             # (1 start)
      {
      (                             # (2 start), Inner core to keep
           (?:                           # Cluster group
                [^{}]++                       # Possesive, not {}
             |                              # or,
                (?1)                          # Recurse to group 1
           )*                            # End cluster, do 0 to many times
      )                             # (2 end)
      }
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: This is great! But you misunderstood my question, perhaps. I want the exact inverse of the selection your regex produces. I want to remove `\only{` and `}`, and keep everything within it.

Comment: @Kartik - Oh sorry. I've updated the answer to solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, no problem !

Answer (score 2):

Regexes cannot count, as expressed in this famous SO answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

In addition, LaTeX itself has a fairly complicated grammar (i.e. macro expansions?). Ideally, you'd use a parser of some kind, but perhaps that's a little overkill. If you're looking for a really simple, quick and dirty hack **which will only work for a certain class of inputs** you can:

- Search for `\only`.
- Increment a `counter` every time you see a `{` and decrement it every time you see a `}`. If there is a `\` preceding the `{`, ignore it. (Fancy points if you look for an odd number of `\`.)
- When `counter` gets to 0, you've found the closing `}`.

Again, this is **not reliable**.

Comment: I was afraid someone will say that. I guess I'll hack something together in bash... Thanks for the confirmation, and insight!